# MySQL Memory Usage with many Tables

Tags: mysql, memory-consumption

I have a MySQL with a few 100,000 tables. This is currently the best design for my system, since these tables are not related to each other and select queries will only be down on a single table. In addition, users will most likely not access the same tables very often.

I have 16GB RAM, but after about a day, MySQL consumes about 90% of that, with my total memory use of the system being at 99-100%. I tried numerous things, but simply can't get the memory usage down.

My `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is currently at 8GB, but I had it at 1G with the same issue. I also tried reducing `open_files_limit` but that didn't help either.

Here is my output for

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%Open_%';
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| Com_show_open_tables       | 0        |
| Innodb_num_open_files      | 431      |
| Open_files                 | 0        |
| Open_streams               | 0        |
| Open_table_definitions     | 615      |
| Open_tables                | 416      |
| Opened_files               | 4606655  |
| Opened_table_definitions   | 4598528  |
| Opened_tables              | 4661002  |
| Slave_open_temp_tables     | 0        |
| Table_open_cache_hits      | 30024782 |
| Table_open_cache_misses    | 4661002  |
| Table_open_cache_overflows | 4660579  |
+----------------------------+----------+
```

And here is my mysqld config:

```
sql-mode=''
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
open_files_limit=100000
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
```

Anyone know how to efficiently handle these thousands of tables?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

A) Mysqld: https://pastebin.com/PTiz6uRD

B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: https://pastebin.com/K4sCmvFz

C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: https://pastebin.com/Cc64BAUw

D) MySQLTuner: https://pastebin.com/zLzayi56

E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS: https://pastebin.com/hHDuw6gY

F) top: https://pastebin.com/6WYnSnPm

**TEST AFTER SERVER REBOOT (LITTLE MEMORY CONSUMED):**

A) ulimit -a: https://pastebin.com/FmPrAKHU

B) iostat -x: https://pastebin.com/L0G7H8s4

C) df -h: https://pastebin.com/d3EttR19

D) MySQLTuner: https://pastebin.com/T3DYDLg8

Comment: When you say "a few 100,000 tables" do you really mean like 300,000 tables? You have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask about whatever problem you're trying to solve with that design instead. There's likely a better way to solve it.

Comment: The tables have the same structure, but users select all rows in a table. So instead of having a single very large table with (millions of records) that requires filtering using WHERE to get a subset, I rather have many tables (each with a few thousand records). I then have to only select the table and get all rows out in one go, without the need of a WHERE part. So select statements should be a lot faster by using many tables instead.

Comment: Databases are designed to have millions of records, not hundreds of thousands of tables. Speeding up `where` queries is what [indexes are for](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization-indexes.html). With good indexes it doesn't matter how many rows are in a table. Again, I advise you to ask about your database design. I think you will learn a lot.

Comment: @goocreations Queries without WHERE will destroy your response time.  Basic rule of any processing, reduce the rows required at the earliest moment.  WHERE should be your favorite and early consideration for any query.  And of course a table with proper indexes enables the minimal rows to be considered quickly.  And using INNODB tables should be high on your list of considerations.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have updated my original post with the new details. I don't have a my.cnf-ini. On Linux I've taken:  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just wanted to get the details, but my server rebooted for some reason. So I will have to wait for a day until the memory fills up again. Will send tomorrow. And what do you mean by the ENTIRE mysqltuner report, do you mean: mysqltuner --verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First block to remove will be in Linux command line,
ulimit -n 124000             to get past the current limit of 1024 Open Files
this can be done NOW, no shutdown/restart of Linux is required for this to be active.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
table_open_cache=10000  # from 431 available today to a practical upper limit
table_definition_cache=10000  # from 615 available today to a practical upper limit
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 for V8 refman CAP suggested to avoid OOM
max_heap_table_size=64M  # from 16M to reduce created_tmp_disk_tables
tmp_table_size=64M  # from 16M should always be equal to max_heap_table_size
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce CPU workload every SECOND
innodb_log_buffer_size=512M  # from 50M to avoid log rotation every 7 minutes
```

Considering your situation, I would SKIP the one a day rule and monitor before 
next Global Variable change.  Make all cnf changes.  Stop/start services required because you are limited to open_files_limit in MySQL even though you requested 100,000 ulimit caused runtime to limit you to 1024.

If you copy paste the block to the END of the MySQLD section,
remove same named variables above the block in MYSQLD section only, 
you will get rid of the 'multiple variable confusion' for the next analyst.

Please view profile for contact information and get in touch.

Comment: I figured out that my server had an open relay, and someone was using it for spam. I think that filled up my mysql's memory. I have fixed the relay, and now it seems that mysql is capped at my innodb_buffer_pool_size limit. Will continue observing it for a while to see if this is indeed the case. Thanks for the help.